How to use chemfig package?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


\chemfig∗6(−[:60](−[::−60]CH_3)−[:−60](−[::−60]CH_3)−[:−60]CH_3)

\end{document}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Usually helps to read package documentation :-)

Your question is not very clear, but I will try to answer.
The correct command is \chemfig{}, don't forget the "{}"
To create a hexagonal ring, the command is *6(------) or *6(-=-=-=)
To add branches to the ring:
If there is only one branch on a given carbon, use (-CH_3), you don't need to specify the angle.
If there are two branches on a carbon ()() and now you need to specify the angles of the branches.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-(-CH_3)--(-CH_3)--(-H_3C)-)}
\end{document}


